# Real Time Machine

Tags: time-travel, science

Is there an existing time machine in film or literature that exists or is specifically based on research in the applied sciences?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Welcome! Please check out the [about] page to see why this question might not be a good fit here.

Comment: @Joseph I would like you to read the book PHYSICS OF THE IMPOSSIBLE by Michio Kaku- Chapter 12 for more detail about Time travel. You can clarify all your doubts about Time Machine briefly in there...

Comment: @Ganesh Or Paul J. Nahin's book [*Time Machines*](http://www.amazon.com/Time-Machines-Physics-Metaphysics-Science/dp/0387985719).

Answer (score 9):

That depends on your definition of a time-machine. Relativity is used in many works of fiction to describe time-travel to the future, notably in several of Arthur C. Clarke's short-stories, including in the *Songs of Distant Earth* anthology.

The *Orphans of Earth* trilogy by Sean Williams and Shane Dix includes a communications array that is based on present scientific theories, which is theorised as potentially violating causality; the array allows instantaneous communication, which may only be possible if the message actually travels to the past, then progresses through time to its destination. Williams and Dix don't pick a side in the debate; they merely present it through two of the trilogy's characters arguing with one another, then the debate is cut short by the arrival of another character.

There are several scientific theories regarding the use of black holes for time travel. *Star Trek* has notably used several time travel plots involving black holes, some of them more believable - or, more accurately, less ridiculous - than others. Frederick Pohl also used black holes for time travel in his *Gateway* series, though that was only through the use of relativity. He also based those stories on theories about black holes that have since been disproven, meaning his time machine is not, strictly speaking, possible according to current scientific thought.

As far as time machines allowing travel to the past, while I'm sure there is some obscure work, in a short story or short film, out there somewhere that utilises up-to-date, accurate research on time travel, there is nothing mainstream, unfortunately.

Except for Deloreans, of course. They're real, though they don't really travel through time. But sitting in one does feel a lot like the mid-'eighties.